# Sieve of Eratosthenes in Delphi Pascal 5

Tags: delphi

I am very new to programming, especially in Delphi Pascal. Now I have to do the Sieve of Eratosthenes as school-homework. While I do try to learn the basics, please forgive me, if I´m just struggling with a simple Problem, because I do not have the time to learn everything unfortunately.
I do have a little bit of code already but while it isn't showing an error it just does not do anything? I know that I need to write something in order for it to show a product but I'm not really sure how to do that either.
Help would be very appreciated.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Berechnen: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure BerechnenClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}




procedure TForm1.BerechnenClick(Sender: TObject);
const
n = 200;
var
   zahl : array [2..n] of boolean;
   p,i,v : integer;
   weiter : boolean;
begin
   for i := 2 to n do zahl[i] := true;
   p := 2;
   while p <= n do
   begin
        v := 2*p;
        while v <= n do
        begin
             zahl[v] := false;
             v := v+p;
        end;
        p := p+1;
        if p <= n then weiter := true;
        while weiter do
         if (p<=n) and (zahl[p] = false)
         then
           p := p+1
         else
           weiter := false;
           end;
           end;

end.
```

Comment: You can debug a simple program like this by single-stepping it in the debugger by pressing F8 repeatedly.  Try that ...

Comment: Is your school still using Delphi 5!?

Comment: https://lp.embarcadero.com/Object-Pascal-Handbook-2021

Comment: Yes, unfortunately :/ We wanted Java, but our teacher said Delphi 5 would be better. And thanks.

Comment: If you haven't got time to learn, isn't that the real problem? Why don't you find time?

Comment: Pascal was designed as a teaching language, so that's absolutely ok. But please tell your teacher about the academic program of Embarcadero. Or at least about Lazarus, because Delphi 5 is sooo old!

Comment: Our teacher did not give us any kind of introduction. It is kind of difficult getting it by myself.

Comment: Delphi 5 is not bad instrument to learn basic algorithms and simple programming concepts. @Schreiberkugel Your question is not bad - I suppose it was downvoted because you wrote "I do not have the time.."

Comment: Well that is understandable, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your program does mark primes in the `zahl` array correctly, but you have to output the results to see it. Add this code:

```
for i := 2 to n do
    if zahl[i] then
        memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i));
```

Side notes:

- Simple educational programs usually don't require complex interfaces - you can create a console application with `readln`/`writeln` etc.
- It is worth to create a function/procedure to separate working code from interface tasks (input/output, data organization).
- Delphi 5 can work with dynamic arrays (`array of ...` and `SetLength`), so you could extend your sieve function with an `n` limit defined by the user "on the fly":

  ```
   var 
     n: integer;
     zahl: array of Boolean;
   ...
     n := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
     SetLength(zahl, n+1); //indexed from 0, filled by False
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's actually showing something now. But unfortunately it's always showing the same number that aren't related to the number I type in.

Comment: It prints list of primes less than 200.  What is `the number I type in` ????

Comment: oh ok. Its supposed to show the prime numbers of n, the number I type into the edit. I'll look into it again. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to remove `const n` declaration